# Is it possible to combine the settings bundle and main application localisation resources?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization, settings

In the documentation for localising settings bundles, [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html), it seems to imply that the strings in the user defaults are only localised using the .strings files within the settings bundle.

Is it possible to combine these .strings files with the main application's localisation resources so that all translations are in a single location rather than spread across the main application bundle and the settings bundle?

Answer (score 0):

No, bundles have been are meant to encapsulate data contained within them. System settings app cares just about what is inside the settings bundle. On the other hand regular app cares only about what is inside its bundle, by default. I can imagine that it is possible to hack this and store everything in the settings bundle. It is just a matter of creating own NSLocalizedString macros which would search for strings just in the settings bundle, but this creates more problems than solves.